# cocos2d transition between different scenes in iphone

Tags: iphone, ipad, cocos2d-iphone, scene, sprite-sheet

I am intending to develop a story book using cocos2d. So i think i want to create scenes corresponding to the book pages. The book may consist of some 100 pages. So creating that much scene will be redundant. Is there any other ways in cocos2d for implementing the book pages and transition between pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all,

If you are thinking about specifying each page of the book as a separated in order to define a particular scene, you will get in trouble :)

It would be much better to specify each scene in a .plist file. Define all the Book page content in a Key-Value fashion using several plists (one per page for example), and then just code a "Page Loader" Class which takes a *page_X.plist* file and return a Scene Object in your app.

Something like:

Scene *loaded = [SceneLoader sceneFromFile:@"page_1.plist"];

For the transitions, each plist should contain information about how to transition your particular scene, you should take at [CCTransitionTurnPage](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/latest-stable/interface_c_c_transition_page_turn.html)

Good luck!

Comment: I think CCTransition page can be used only with CCReplaceScene. But replacing some 50 scenes will lead to application crash due to memory warning. So is there any other method to the page turn with turning effect.

Comment: Replace scene does not take more memory, I think you're getting confused with PushScene, take a look here: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:lesson_3._menus_and_scenes

Comment: But my app is crashing when turning some 20 pages. Will replace scene remove the currently running scene from stack?

Comment: Well, if you are not using ARC, I would recommend you to perform your respective releases manually when replacing scenes. I think this is not associated to this question anymore though :)

Comment: I remove the crash while replacing scene by using purgeCachedData.